# Debugging Zend Framework project with NetBeans / XDebug

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, xdebug

Has anyone been able to set up NetBeans debugging of a Zend Framework project? I have XAMPP running locally on my machine, as well as NetBeans 6.8. From the looks of phpinfo(), XDebug is properly installed on XAMPP. I start debugging session with NetBeans, it connects to XDebug and the page opens, however it will not stop at any break point.

This is an excerpt from the NetBeans log if you're interested:

```
<response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug"      command="step_into" transaction_id="165" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
FINE [org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.ServerThread]
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
[catch] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This timeout looks suspicious, but I'm not sure if it's causing the problem.

This is an excerpt from my php.ini configuration:

```
extension=php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.3-vc6.dll
xdebug.extended_info = 1
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it. The problem is that XDebug had to be enabled through Zend Extension Manager (not through regular PHP extensions), and there was no Zend Extension Manager in XAMPP 1.7.2 (which I had). I downgraded to XAMPP 1.7.0 and it worked. I also had to disable Zend Optimizer and download a newer version of XDebug. This is my final PHP configuration:

```
[Zend]
zend_extension_ts = "\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\ZendExtensionManager.dll"
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts = "\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\Optimizer"
;zend_optimizer.enable_loader = 1
;zend_optimizer.optimization_level=15
;zend_optimizer.license_path =
; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:

[XDebug]
;; Only Zend OR (!) XDebug
zend_extension_ts="\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.2.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
```